# Дополнительный атрибут для option

Tags: html, javascript

У меня есть список:

```
<select name="variantId" onchange="alert($(this).has('option:selected').attr('data-price'));">
<option value="209" data-price="4000">500 мл</option>
<option value="208" data-price="1850">250 мл</option>
<option value="207" data-price="950">100 мл</option>
<option value="206" data-price="460">50 мл</option>
<option value="205" data-price="220">25 мл</option>
<option value="204" data-price="100">10 мл</option>
</select>
```

Почему он не выводит цену из атрибута data-price, а пишет undefined?
Может потому что у меня xhtml, а data-price из html5?

Тогда какой можно использовать атрибут, чтобы задать 3-й параметр для поля?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RTFM .has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

> Description: Reduce the set of matched
> elements to those that have a
> descendant that matches the selector
> or DOM element.

```
<select name="variantId" onchange="alert($(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-price'));">
```